# Issue with custom navigation controller iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have created a custom navigation controller  in appDelegate :

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

poemsView  = [[[PoemsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PoemsViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:poemsView] autorelease];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;


self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

so the problem is I need my app lunches from viewController , but if I set my viewController as rootviewController , my navigation controller does not push navigation and vice versa , if set my navigation controller as a root , app does not load from menus or main view controller .

Comment: How are you customizing your navigation bar? Typical solutions range from using `appearance` customize the appearance of the standard navigation controller, to putting a category on `UINavigationBar` and replacing its `drawRect`. Can you explain what you're trying to do in your customization? You generally don't want to subclass `UINavigationController` (not that that's what you've done), but I'm not clear what you're trying to do. Recommendations will vary depending upon what effect you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What's the purpose of ViewController? If you're using it for something temporary, like a login or splash screen, I would present it modally from PoemsViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you Creating Poemsview as rootviewcontroller of Navigation Controller ?

if You Want To Load ViewController First Then use the following Code.

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

poemsView  = [[[PoemsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PoemsViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController] autorelease];

self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;



self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

You Can Create Another Navigation Controller as a `Sub-class of Viewcontroller.`

In your Poem Button Action Add The Following :

```
// Create a regular view controller.
PoemViewController *modalViewController = [[[PoemViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PoemViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

// Create a navigation controller containing the view controller.
UINavigationController *secondNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:modalViewController];

// Present the navigation controller as a modal view controller on top of an existing navigation controller
[self presentModalViewController:secondNavigationController animated:YES];
```

Now You can be able push To detail View from Your `tableview DidselectRowAtindexpath` .

Comment: I know but then navigation controller does not push in detailViewController for example because its root is not defined !

Comment: did you checked my code here `self.viewcontroller` is `rootviewcontroller` .

Comment: He's right, your rootViewController here is the navigation controller and it has self.viewController at the bottom of the stack.It should work, try it.

Comment: thanks but your code does not push poemsViewController to the detail view controller , as I said :)

Comment: ViewController is my main view which menus are there , then user tap Poems button  , which presents  PoesmViewController via modal transition style . then I have a table view there , user touch each cell and then it should push to the detailViewController PoemsViewContrller inherits from UIViewController class not UINAvigationController so I define a custom navigation controller

Comment: @Momi Check my Edited Answer.Initially your question was not Clear And now only i understood What you trying to do.